# asyncstorage.getitem('key') retorna la promesa o [object object]

Tags: android, react-native, redux, async, expo

Estoy tratando de poder tomar una variable del asynstorage.getitem() pero cuando retorno el valor me devuelve la promesa o me devuelve un object, por lo que no se que estoy haciendo mal, esto lo hago en un action en redux

a continuacion el codigo que uso para guardar en el storage

```
  Guardar = async (data) => {
  try {
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('IdPersona', JSON.stringify(data.user.persona_id));
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('access_token', data.access_token);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("error->" +error.message)
  }
}
```

};

y a continuación el action

```
export function BuscarParvularia() {
return (dispatch) => {

console.log(key()); //-> esta funcion es la que llamo y me devuelve lo 
                         indicado

axios({
  method: 'get',
  url: 'http://misitio.api.cl/api/parvularia/DatosParvularia/',
}).then(Response => {
  const data = Response.data;
  dispatch({ type: DATA_AVAILABLE, data: data });
});
};
}
```

y a continuacion la funcion key();

```
key = async () => {

    var value, collect;
    try {
      value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('IdPersona').then(
        (values) => {
          collect = values;
          console.log('Then: ', values);
        });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Error: ', error);
    }
    console.log('Final: ', value);
    return collect;
  }
```

Comment: Y en qué momento llamas a tu función `Guardar` o cual es la línea que esperas que no retorne promesa, ya que veo dos lugares donde llamas al `AsyncStorage`

Comment: perdon error mio no espeficique esa parte, es cuando llamo el key() ese es el que va a buscar la variable que necesito, editare la pregunta

Comment: Vale, si llamas a tu así a tu método `key()` te retorna una promesa, porque estás definiendo a `key` como asíncrono, por lo que debes llamarle un `then` o con `await`. Yo te recomiendo que a tu función `BuscarParvularia` la definas asíncrona, así: `async BuscarParvularia` y luego cuando hagas el log, lo haces así: `console.log(await key())`

Comment: @GermanAlzate muchas gracias lo probare, pero de ser asi tendre algun problema desde donde estoy llamando el action? saludos

Comment: No, tu puedes llamarlo de donde sea, me acabo de fijar que estás retornando una función por lo que también es necesario ponerle un async en el return, quedando así tu return: `return async (dispatch) => {`

Comment: @GermanAlzate gracias o implementare y te comento para que lo respondas como pregunta y te ganes tus merecidos puntos

Comment: @GermanAlzate me da error, al parecer la funcion del action no puede ser async

Comment: Entonces hazla "theneable", no había caído en cuenta que era un action. Pero entonces olvidando los `async` y los `await` puedes usar promesas. Llamándola así: `key().then(console.log)`

Comment: Si estimado al final lo que hice la llamada de mi action lo puse en el interior del then que llama a mi async storage al menos funciono bien para mi

Answer (score 0):

Esto funciono para mi no soy experto pero fue lo que me hizo mas sentido

```
export const DATA_AVAILABLE = 'DATA_AVAILABLE';
import axios from 'axios'
import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';

export function BuscarParvularia() {
  return (dispatch) => {

    ObteneridPersona().then(Response => { // llamo el metodo y en el then coloco la logica de llamado 
      let idpersona = Response; // seteo la variable
      axios({        
        method: 'get',
        url: 'http://equalshost.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com/api/parvularia/DatosParvularia/' + idpersona, //la anido a mi request de la api

      }).then(Response => {
         const data = JSON.stringify(Response.data);
         saveData(data);
        dispatch({ type: DATA_AVAILABLE, data: data }); // despacho la info
      });
    })
  };
}
ObteneridPersona = async () => {
  var collect;
  try {
    value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('IdPersona').then(
      (values) => {
        collect = values;      
      });
  } catch (error) {
    return 'action -> ' + error
  }
  return await collect;
}

saveData = async (data) => {
  try {
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('MY_DATA', data.nivelcurso)
  } catch (error) {
    return await "Error action save data -> " + error
  }
}
```